# Python Django Pagination + Bootstrap columns

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Need recommendations or little help how to list insert in columns using Django built-in Pagination and Bootstrap.

For example. I have list with pagination. Every page have for example 9 results. But it all is in one column. I want to using Bootstrap row/column (col-md-4) to insert this list in 3 columns/3 rows. Is that with django Pagination possible or not? How? Or what you recommend?

This is my template code, where i make 3 columns with bootstrap. But all columns have 9 results and all column results are the same!

```
{% if project %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                {% for projects in project %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ current_page.get_absolute_url }}{{ project.slug }}">
                        <img src="{{ projects.main_image.image|thumbnail_url:'projects_top_thumbnail' }}" alt="{{ projects.title }}" />
                        <div class="showcase-title">
                            {{ projects.title }}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                {% for projects in project %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ current_page.get_absolute_url }}{{ project.slug }}">
                        <img src="{{ projects.main_image.image|thumbnail_url:'projects_top_thumbnail' }}" alt="{{ projects.title }}" />
                        <div class="showcase-title">
                            {{ projects.title }}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                {% for projects in project %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ current_page.get_absolute_url }}{{ project.slug }}">
                        <img src="{{ projects.main_image.image|thumbnail_url:'projects_top_thumbnail' }}" alt="{{ projects.title }}" />
                        <div class="showcase-title">
                            {{ projects.title }}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            <div class="pagination">
                <span class="step-links">
                    {% if project.has_previous %}
                        <a href="?page={{ project.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                    {% endif %}

                <span class="current">
                    Page {{ project.number }} of {{ project.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>

                    {% if project.has_next %}
                        <a href="?page={{ project.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endif %}

Comment: show us the code of what you've tried so far

Comment: Insert my code in first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
            {% for projects in project %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ current_page.get_absolute_url }}{{ project.slug }}">
                            <img src="{{ projects.main_image.image|thumbnail_url:'projects_top_thumbnail' }}" alt="{{ projects.title }}" />
                            <div class="showcase-title">
                                {{ projects.title }}
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>                                
                </div>   
            {% endfor %}
</div>
            <div class="pagination">
            <span class="step-links">
                {% if project.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page={{ project.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                Page {{ project.number }} of {{ project.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>

                {% if project.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ project.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

If you are looking for a grid of 3X3 Then the above code solves that.